# Fine-Uploader Access is denied

Tags: internet-explorer-9, fine-uploader

I am using the basic Fine Uploader.
I am getting the message Access is denied in native IE9 (not in IE11 with IE9 compatibility)
It happens when I select the upload button, I mean, previously I select the file and it is added fine. Then I click in the button that calls the service and I get the error.

I read that it could be a security setting in IE, but not sure why it works in IE11 with compatibility and in other browsers and not in native IE9.

Here is the console log:

***LOG: [FineUploader 4.2.1] Received 1 files or inputs. 
LOG: [FineUploader 4.2.1] Sending upload request for 0 
Error: Access is denied.

LOG: [FineUploader 4.2.1] Received response for 0_940f74c7-55dd-4ff2-a4b9-a01a2a80a917***

Is there any workaround for it?

Regards,

[Edit]

(I deleted some functions that are not used when I upload the file, just to make the code shorter here)

JS (angular controller)

```
  dApp.controller('BPDocumentsController',['$scope', 'BPDocument', 'BPDocuments',
      function BPDocumentsController($scope, BPDocument, BPDocuments) {
       var manualuploader = null;

       $scope.resetUploadDocumentForm = function () {
           $("input[type='file']").val(null);
           $scope.seletedFile = '';
           $scope.fileToUpload = null;
           $scope.documentTitle = '';
           $scope.certify = false;
           $scope.yourName = '';
           $scope.yourTitle = '';
       };

       $scope.resetCustomValidations= function () {
           $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("filetype", true);
           $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("size", true);
           $scope.uploadDocumentForm.documentTitle.$setValidity("documentTitleUnique", true);
       };

       $scope.closeUploadDocumentForm = function () {
           $scope.resetUploadDocumentForm();
           $scope.resetCustomValidations();
           $scope.uploadDocumentForm.$setPristine(true);
           $scope.showPopUp = false;
       };



       $scope.uploadDocument = function () {

           var model = {
               BusinessPartnerId: $scope.businessPartnerId,
               Title: $scope.documentTitle,
               CertifiedByName : $scope.yourName,
               CertifiedByTitle: $scope.yourTitle
           };
           var data = { model: model  };

           manualuploader.setParams(model);
           manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();

           //clean and close popup
           $scope.closeUploadDocumentForm();         
       };

       function initializeFileUploadControl() {
           manualuploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
               element: document.getElementById('manual-fine-uploader'),
               request: {
                   endpoint:  bpDetailsServiceUrl + "BPDocuments"
               },
               autoUpload: false,
               multiple: false,
               validation: {
                   sizeLimit: $scope.fileMaxSizeInBytes,
                   allowedExtensions: $scope.allowedExtensions
               },
               messages: {
                   typeError: "invalidFileExtension",
                   sizeError: "invalidFileSize"
               },
               debug: true,

               callbacks: {
                   onComplete:
                     function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {

                         var document = new Object();
                         document = {
                             BusinessPartnerDocumentId: responseJSON.BusinessPartnerDocumentId,
                             FileExtension: responseJSON.FileExtension,
                             Title: responseJSON.Title
                         };

                         $scope.companyTabSelected ? $scope.companyDocumentList.push(document) : $scope.bpDocumentList.push(document);
                         $scope.$apply();
                     },
                   onError: function(id, fileName, reason, maybeXhr) {
                       if (reason == 'invalidFileExtension') {
                           $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("filetype", false);
                       }
                       if (reason == 'invalidFileSize') {
                           $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("size", false);
                       }

                   }
               }
           })


       };

       $scope.setFile = function () {
           $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {
               $scope.fileToUpload = null;
               $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("filetype", true);
               $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("size", true);

               $scope.fileName = document.getElementById("fileId");
               $scope.fileToUpload = $scope.fileName != undefined && $scope.fileName != '';

               manualuploader.clearStoredFiles();
               manualuploader.addFiles($scope.fileName);

           });
       };

       initializeModel();
       initializeFileUploadControl();

       function initializeModel() {
           var data = JSON.parse($("#BusinessPartnerDocumentData").html());

           $scope.allowedExtensions = ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf'];

           $scope.showCompanyTab = data.ShowCompanyTab;
           $scope.showBPTab = data.ShowBPTab;
           $scope.companyDocumentList = data.CompanyDocumentList;
           $scope.bpDocumentList = data.BPDocumentList;
           $scope.uploadButtonEnabled = data.UploadButtonEnabled;
           $scope.fileMaxSizeInBytes = data.FileMaxSizeInBytes;
           $scope.businessPartnerId = data.BusinessPartnerId;
           $scope.fileName = '';
           $scope.companyTabSelected = $scope.showCompanyTab;
           $scope.bpTabSelected = !$scope.showCompanyTab && $scope.showBPTab ? true : false;
           $scope.resetUploadDocumentForm();
       }
   }]);
```

***HTML***

```
  <div ng-controller="BPDocumentsController">
        <div class="ng-modal" ng-show="showPopUp">
       <div class="ng-modal-overlay"></div>
       <div class="ng-modal-dialog dcp-color-box">
           <div class="ng-modal-close" ng-click="closeUploadDocumentForm()">X</div>
           <div class="pop-up-title">
            <span>{{translations["lblAcceptableFormats"]}}&nbsp;{{allowedExtensions.join(', ')}}</span>

        </div>
        <div class="ng-modal-dialog-content dcp-white-box wdt-500">



            <ng-form name="uploadDocumentForm" novalidate="">
        <div class="pdn-b10 pop-up-note">
            <span class="alert-col">* </span>
            <span>{{translations["lblIndicatesRequiredField"]}}</span> 
        </div>

        <div class="dcp-label-title">
            {{translations["lblChooseDocumentUpload"]}}
            <span class="alert-col">*</span>
        </div>
             <input type="file" id="fileId" name="file" ng-model="tempFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile()"/>
        <div ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.file.$invalid">
            <span class="error-message" ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.file.$error.size">{{translations["lblFilesNotLargerThan5MB"]}}</span>
            <span class="error-message" ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.file.$error.filetype">{{translations["lblAcceptableFormats"]}}&nbsp;{{allowedExtensions.join(', ')}}</span>
        </div> 

        <div class="dcp-label-title">
            {{translations["lblDocumentTitle"]}}
            <span class="alert-col">*</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="documentTitle" class="dcp-form-textbox wdt-250 mrg-b10" ng-model="documentTitle" ng-minlength=3 ng-blur="lookUpDocument()" required />
        <div ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.documentTitle.$dirty && uploadDocumentForm.documentTitle.$invalid">
            <span class="error-message" ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.documentTitle.$error.minlength">{{translations["cvTitleMinimumLength"]}}</span>
            <span class="error-message" ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.documentTitle.$error.documentTitleUnique">{{translations["lblTitleError"]}}</span>
        </div>            
        <div class="pop-up-note-b mrg-b10 clearfix">
            <span>{{translations["lblTitleDocumentCenter"]}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <input type="checkbox" name="certify" ng-model="certify" required/>
            <span>{{translations["cbCertify"]}}</span>
            <span class="error-message">*</span>
        </div>

        <div class="dcp-label-title">
            {{translations["lblYourName"]}}
            <span class="error-message">*</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="yourName" class="dcp-form-textbox wdt-250 mrg-b10" ng-model="yourName" required />

        <div class="dcp-label-title">
            {{translations["lblYourTitle"]}}
            <span class="error-message">*</span>
        </div>
        <input type ="text" name="yourTitle" class="dcp-form-textbox wdt-250 mrg-b10" ng-model="yourTitle" ng-minlength=3 required/>
        <div ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.yourTitle.$dirty && uploadDocumentForm.yourTitle.$invalid">
            <span class="error-message" ng-show="uploadDocumentForm.yourTitle.$error.minlength">{{translations["cvTitleMinimumLength"]}}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="dcp-box-buttons">
            <span class="f-l">{{now}}</span>
            <button type="button" ng-click="uploadDocument()" ng-disabled="uploadDocumentForm.$invalid || !fileToUpload" ng-class="{'dcp-color-btn-disable':uploadDocumentForm.$invalid || !fileToUpload, 'dcp-color-btn':uploadDocumentForm.$valid && fileToUpload}">{{translations["btnSubmit"]}}</button>
            <button type="reset" class="dcp-color-btn" ng-click="closeUploadDocumentForm()">{{translations["btnCancel"]}}</button>
        </div>
</ng-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EXTRA BUTTON:

```
function initializeFileUploadControl() {
            manualuploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
                element: document.getElementById('manual-fine-uploader'),
                request: {
                endpoint:  bpDetailsServiceUrl + "BPDocuments"
            },
            autoUpload: false,
            multiple: false,
            validation: {
                sizeLimit: $scope.fileMaxSizeInBytes,
                allowedExtensions: $scope.allowedExtensions
            },
            extraButtons: [
                 {
                     element: $("#pdfButton"),
                 }
                    ],
            messages: {
                typeError: "invalidFileExtension",
                sizeError: "invalidFileSize"
            },
            debug: true,

            callbacks: {
                onComplete:
                  function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {

                      var document = new Object();
                      document = {
                          BusinessPartnerDocumentId: responseJSON.BusinessPartnerDocumentId,
                          FileExtension: responseJSON.FileExtension,
                          Title: responseJSON.Title
                      };

                      $scope.companyTabSelected ? $scope.companyDocumentList.push(document) : $scope.bpDocumentList.push(document);
                      $scope.$apply();
                  },
                onError: function(id, fileName, reason, maybeXhr) {
                    if (reason == 'invalidFileExtension') {
                        $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("filetype", false);
                    }
                    if (reason == 'invalidFileSize') {
                        $scope.uploadDocumentForm.file.$setValidity("size", false);
                    }

                }
            }
        })


    };
```

HTML for extra button:

```
 <div id="pdfButton" style="background-color:gray">Select a PDF</div>
 <div id="uploader"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question where the error is occuring.  Does the issue happen before the file is sent, or when the response comes in from your server?  If it is the former, then you need to show your client-side code.  If it is the latter, there is an issue with your server response.

Comment: The issue happen before the file is sent. I added the portion of code where the file is sent. Let me know if you need further information.

Comment: You aren't showing enough code.  You'll need to show ALL of the client-side code related to your integration of Fine Uploader.  Most likely,  you are triggering the file chooser dialog using javascript, which is not allowed in IE.

Comment: You are right, I am calling the click event for the input type file, since I had to make a tricky, because in IE9 when I select the file and I get the DOM element, after calling manualuploader.addFiles(document.getElementById("fileId"); it dissapear, but it is still added in the collection of manualuploader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [FAQ on docs.fineuploader.com](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/faq.html), you cannot programatically trigger a file chooser dialog.  This is not a Fine Uploader limitation, it is a security restriction that Internet Explorer takes quite seriously.

There is no obvious reason to programmatically invoke a file chooser dialog with Fine Uploader anyway, as it provides you with a [default customizable file chooser button](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#button) and the [ability to contribute additional chooser buttons](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/extra-buttons.html).  You must allow your user to click these buttons.  If you need to programmatically submit a `<input type="file">`, `File` or `Blob` to Fine Uploader, you can do this via the [`addFiles`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles) or [`addBlobs`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addBlobs) API methods.

Comment: I do with addFiles, but for some reason after addFiles is called the input type file disapear, however the file is saved properly. It just happen in IE9. Is there any know issue with that?

Comment: Please provide exact code (JavaScript and HTML) required to reproduce this issue, and also please explain what you mean by "disappears".

Comment: I added the code above. By "disappears" I mean that the input type file is deleted from the page and from the HTML code (if you inspect it, it is not there any more). It happens in the SetFile function.

Comment: You are correct, it looks like Fine Uploader will remove the file input from the DOM in this case.  I have filed a [defect report in Fine Uploader's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1126).  We are releasing 4.3.0 on Monday, but I expect to look into this immediately after the planned release and perhaps fix this in a 4.3.1 hotfix.  A workaround would be to attach this upload button to Fine Uploader using the [extra buttons feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/extra-buttons.html).

Comment: I've updated that issue from a bug to a documentation.  I've explained my reasoning in the issue, please have a look.  The way to deal with this issue is either to attach your input to Fine Uploader via the `button` or `extraButtons` options, or clone and re-add the file input to the DOM after submitting it to Fine Uploader via addFiles.

Comment: I will tray the workaround. Do you have any tentative date for this hotfix? I have to analize if I have to change the library or if I can wait until it is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: There probably won't be a hotfix.  Please read the last message in the issue I created and add any comments you may have to that issue.

Comment: Thanks, I try to create the extraButton but It does not work.
I get the error:
Error: Can't apply style to node as it is not on the HTMLElement 
Maybe I missunderstood how to use it. Remember I am using the basic fineUploader.
Also I tried to clone it, but I get the message saying that the extensions are not valid.

Comment: You need to set the element property of each extraButton to an actual HTMLElement.

Comment: You're passing a jQuery object as the element, not an HTMLElement.  If you want to pass a jQuery object, you must use the Fine Uploader jQuery plug-in.